# Lucene DuplicateFilter problems

Tags: c#, search, lucene

I'm using Lucene to search over this table of objects:

```
name        | category 
============|==========
John Smith  | Dogs     
John Smith  | Cats
```

I'm using DuplicateFilter to get only one result for each person.

My problem is when I'm searching for the term "John Smith Dogs" with the DuplicateFilter I get no results. Is there an easy solution for this problem?

Comment: The query is basically "john" AND "smith" AND "dogs", and before using DuplicateFilter I got the right result for this query.

Comment: With java there is a bug in duplicate filter [DuplicateFilter incorrectly handles multiple calls to getDocIdSet for segment readers](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2348).
If your index is divided into multiple segments, you have to merge it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue recently with the multiple segments not removing duplicates across boundaries. I wrote a little hack in my own custom `DuplicateFilter` class to cross the boundaries the first time it is called and return the cached bit sets with subsequent calls. I only implemented the `CorrectBits` (used for `PM_FULL_VALIDATION`) method but it should be trivial to implement the FastBits (used for `PM_FAST_INVALIDATION`) one as well based on the original code.

```
/*
* Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
* contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
* this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
* The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
* (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
* the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.Util;

namespace Lucene.Net.Search
{
    public class DuplicateFilter : Filter
    {
        public static int KM_USE_FIRST_OCCURRENCE = 1;
        public static int KM_USE_LAST_OCCURRENCE = 2;
        public static int PM_FAST_INVALIDATION = 2;
        public static int PM_FULL_VALIDATION = 1;
        private string fieldName;

        /*
         * KeepMode determines which document id to consider as the master, all others being
         * identified as duplicates. Selecting the "first occurrence" can potentially save on IO.
         */
        private int keepMode = KM_USE_FIRST_OCCURRENCE;
        /*
         * "Full" processing mode starts by setting all bits to false and only setting bits
         * for documents that contain the given field and are identified as none-duplicates.

         * "Fast" processing sets all bits to true then unsets all duplicate docs found for the
         * given field. This approach avoids the need to read TermDocs for terms that are seen
         * to have a document frequency of exactly "1" (i.e. no duplicates). While a potentially
         * faster approach , the downside is that bitsets produced will include bits set for
         * documents that do not actually contain the field given.
         *
         */
        private int processingMode = PM_FULL_VALIDATION;

        private object SetupLock = new object();

        public DuplicateFilter(string fieldName) : this(fieldName, KM_USE_LAST_OCCURRENCE, PM_FULL_VALIDATION)
        {
        }

        public DuplicateFilter(string fieldName, int keepMode, int processingMode)
        {
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
            this.keepMode = keepMode;
            this.processingMode = processingMode;
        }

        public string FieldName
        {
            get => fieldName;
            set => fieldName = value;
        }

        public int KeepMode
        {
            get => keepMode;
            set => keepMode = value;
        }

        public int ProcessingMode
        {
            get => processingMode;
            set => processingMode = value;
        }

        private IDictionary<string, (OpenBitSet Filtered, OpenBitSet Hit)> SegmentBits
        {
            get;
            set;
        } = new Dictionary<string, (OpenBitSet Filtered, OpenBitSet Hit)>();

        private bool SetupComplete
        {
            get;
            set;
        } = false;

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if ((obj == null) || (obj.GetType() != GetType())) {
                return false;
            }
            var other = (DuplicateFilter)obj;
            return keepMode == other.keepMode &&
            processingMode == other.processingMode &&
                (fieldName == other.fieldName || (fieldName != null && fieldName.Equals(other.fieldName)));
        }

        public override DocIdSet GetDocIdSet(IndexReader reader)
        {
            if (processingMode == PM_FAST_INVALIDATION) {
                return FastBits(reader);
            } else {
                return CorrectBits(reader);
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            var hash = 217;
            hash = 31 * hash + keepMode;
            hash = 31 * hash + processingMode;
            hash = 31 * hash + fieldName.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }

        private OpenBitSet CorrectBits(IndexReader reader)
        {
            SetupCorrect(reader);
            return SegmentBits[((SegmentReader)reader).GetSegmentName()].Filtered;
        }

        private OpenBitSet FastBits(IndexReader reader)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void SetupCorrect(IndexReader reader)
        {
            lock (SetupLock) {
                if (!SetupComplete) {
                    // Get segment readers and bitsets.
                    var segmentReaders = new Dictionary<string, SegmentReader>();
                    var sis = new SegmentInfos();
                    sis.Read(reader.Directory());
                    foreach (SegmentInfo si in sis) {
                        var r = SegmentReader.Get(true, si, 1);
                        segmentReaders.Add(si.name, r);
                        SegmentBits.Add(si.name, (new OpenBitSet(r.MaxDoc()), new OpenBitSet(r.MaxDoc())));
                    }
                    // Determine duplicates across segments.
                    foreach (var outerKvp in segmentReaders) {
                        var startTerm = new Term(fieldName);
                        var te = outerKvp.Value.Terms(startTerm);
                        if (te != null) {
                            var currTerm = te.Term();
                            while ((currTerm != null) && (currTerm.Field() == startTerm.Field())) {
                                var set = false;
                                var lastKey = outerKvp.Key;
                                var lastDoc = -1;
                                foreach (var innerKvp in segmentReaders) {
                                    var td = innerKvp.Value.TermDocs(currTerm);
                                    if (td.Next()) {
                                        var doc = td.Doc();
                                        if (SegmentBits[innerKvp.Key].Hit.Get(doc)) {
                                            // Term has already been hit; skip it.
                                            set = true;
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                        // Keep track of which terms have already been hit.
                                        SegmentBits[innerKvp.Key].Hit.Set(doc);
                                        if (set) {
                                            // Only need to set the first term as hit in each segment.
                                            continue;
                                        } else if (keepMode == KM_USE_FIRST_OCCURRENCE) {
                                            SegmentBits[innerKvp.Key].Filtered.Set(doc);
                                            set = true;
                                        } else {
                                            do {
                                                lastDoc = td.Doc();
                                                lastKey = innerKvp.Key;
                                            } while (td.Next());
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if (!set && keepMode == KM_USE_LAST_OCCURRENCE) {
                                    SegmentBits[lastKey].Filtered.Set(lastDoc);
                                }
                                if (!te.Next()) {
                                    break;
                                }
                                currTerm = te.Term();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Mark setup as complete.
                    SetupComplete = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more of an answer for the linked issue from VolkerK's comment above. The answer for the original question is that it is not able to do that because the `DuplicateFilter` on name is happening before the results are searched. The fix for that would be to implement a custom Collector that would remove duplicates or the canonical answer has been to exclude duplicates when indexing. So this example could have one entry for *John Smith* with two category entries instead.